# Can MVC replace n-tier architecture or is it a part of n-tier architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I'm learning about the MVC architecture these days and I'm confused MVC with the n-tire architecture.

I have seen some saying You can directly use MVC instead of n-tire(3-tire) architecture where View represents UI tire, Controller represents Business or Logic Tire and the Model  represents Data access Tire.

And some says that Only UI Tire of the 3-tire architecture will be replaced by MVC. If so then do we have to duplicate the domain objects in both Model and Logic tire?

Which of the above 2 approaches are correct or are both can be use depending on the requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC and N-Tier are complementary. You can use them both at the same time. MVC replaces the UI layer in this case. N-Tier describes the physical structure whereas MVC is a design-pattern.

A good example could be having an MVC application (UI), communicating with a webservice (Service & Business) that connects to different data sources (DA). Here MVC will allow for more generalized, reusable views and an optimized UI layer.

But MVC does not replace N-Tier.

I hope that helps !

Comment: Hi, so what you are saying is that we can have MVC on the UI layer and then have the other layers like domain and Data Access like the layered architecture.

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I am saying.

Comment: So does we have to duplicate the domain objects  in the Model?

Comment: You either have completely different domain objects in the Model or you reuse class and interface definitions that have to be implemented in a common dll (no duplication please, duplication is never a good solution). You might have different domain objects since they are better adapted to the UI (less data, prepared for UI usage, etc..). The Business/Service Layer has to provide them to the UI in this case.

Answer (score 1):

MVC has lot of benefits over the traditional n-tier architecture. It is dynamic and is good for team working. Designers do their stuff without worrying about the coding aspect while coders can continue their job without worrying about design.

Answer (score 0):

These are quite different patterns.

N-tier is about physical separation of application layers, so you could e.g., swap-out your DAL, or add another frontend.

MVC is on the other hand concerned with interaction between user and application.